# Android Uber login Error integration java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OFFLINE_ACCESS is not a constant in com.uber.sdk.core.auth.Scope

Tags: java, android, uber-api

During uber login integration process, When I am clicking Allow button in Access information page:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OFFLINE_ACCESS is not a constant
>   in com.uber.sdk.core.auth.Scope error is appearing.

The same code was working until 3 days ago.

`compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.3'` is the uber sdk

Full error code:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: uberapp.app.bng.uberapp, PID: 1307
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {uberapp.app.bng.uberapp/uberapp.app.bng.uberapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras)
>   }} to activity
>   {uberapp.app.bng.uberapp/uberapp.app.bng.uberapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OFFLINE_ACCESS is not a constant
>   in com.uber.sdk.core.auth.Scope
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)

Comment: If you use newer versions of android studio `compile '..'` was replaced by `implementation '..'`

Comment: used uber sdk 9.2, which fixed the issue.
https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk